# How to download a file uploaded to the appfolder using the google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I have uploaded multiple audio files from my Android app onto the appfolder space, using the Google Drive API.  Now, I am trying to download a file, from the web, using Google Drive JS API.  I am able to list the uploaded files using `gapi.client.drive.files.list` and I am able to view a file's metadata using `gapi.client.drive.files.get`, but cannot find a way to download the file.

`gapi.client.drive.files.export` fails with error: `Export only supports Google Docs`.  Can someone please suggest a way by which I can download the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @noogui for helping me in arriving at the solution.

Here's what I had to do:

Added an iframe to the page:

```html
<iframe id="audioIframe"></iframe>
```

Then, added the following js to get the file through ajax and append the data received as the `src` of the `iframe`, in order to download it.

```js
function fetchBlob(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token);
    xhr.onload = function () {
      console.log("Got response");
      console.log(this.response);
      callback(this.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      console.log('Failed to fetch ' + url);
    };
    xhr.send();
}

/**
 * @param {String} id Google drive fileId
 */
function download(id) {
    fetchBlob('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + id + '?alt=media', function (data) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type:"audio/amr"}));

      $('#audioIframe').attr('src', url);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to Download Any File from Google Drive using Picker API**

First view the full sample code from [Handling Google Drive Items](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#gdata). Then make changes to this methods.

```
 function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
          //this tells Drive to show all Files
          addView(new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)). 
          setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
          setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
          setCallback(pickerCallback).
          build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }

function pickerCallback(data) {
  if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    //retrieve the fileID of the chosen file
    var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
    //with the fileID, download the file using webcontentlink         
    var webcontentlink = ' https://docs.google.com/uc?id='+fileId+'&export=download'
    window.open( webcontentlink,'image/png');
  }
}
```

According to [Showing Different Views](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView) ,`google.picker.​ViewId.DOCS or google.picker.​DocsView` shows all the Google Drive items, so in theory the files in the appfolder should be included. Upon running this, a Picker UI will show-up showing all of your Drive files. Select the file and when confirmed, it will be downloaded.

Comment: that does not seem to work for files in the appfolder space

Comment: Then that means files in the appFolder is only accessible by using the app itself, [check here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder), that is Android.

Comment: Yes, that folder is accessible by using the app alone.  And I am developing that app.  I am able to create files in the appfolder, and fetch the list of files in the appfolder and the metadata of those files.  But, I am not able to download the files from the application I am building.

Comment: Let's continue discussion in [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123523/appfolder).